# Select random or urandom as source for SecureRandom in Android

Tags: android, random

How can I select random or urandom as a source of randomness for SecureRandom class in Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't worry about it.

> By default, instances of [`SecureRandom`] will generate an initial seed using an internal entropy source, such as `/dev/urandom`.

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/SecureRandom.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I want to test the randomness of random numbers generated using random or urandom as an entropy source. In Java, this can be set in java.security file but as I cannot find such a file in Android system files, I'm stuck here.

Comment: Perhaps I'm not understanding what you mean by "entropy source" - I read that as synonymous with the seed; is that not what you mean?

Comment: Yes I mean that, as I understand from Android documentation, random and urandom store randomness gathered from the device and used as a seed for SecureRandom. However, I want to specify either of those files as seed for SecureRandom but I couldn't find a way for that. Thanks.